# Migration from older version

Tags: migration, compatibility, webots

Helloo, Folks!

I am tring to migrate from webots 7.4.3 to newest version that's 2019b rev1 but find no clues. For now, when I open old model, some errors occur as following (tons of similar items have been filtered out):

ERROR: '/home/sun/marm/worlds/marm.wbt':1305:5: error: Skipped unknown 'WoodBox' node or PROTO.

WARNING: DEF Marm Robot > DEF leg_rf_shoulder_yaw_HINGE_JOINT HingeJoint > Solid > DEF leg_rf_shoulder_pitch_HINGE_JOINT HingeJoint > Solid > DEF leg_rf_elbow_pitch_HINGE_JOINT HingeJoint > Solid: Webots has detected that this solid is light and oblong according to its inertia matrix. This belongs in the physics edge cases, and can imply weird physical results. Increasing the weight of the object or reducing its eccentricity are recommended.

WARNING: DEF SPHERES Solid: 'name' field value should be unique: 'solid' already used by a sibling Solid node.

WARNING: DEF Marm Robot > DEF leg_rf_shoulder_yaw_HINGE_JOINT HingeJoint > Solid > LED > DEF COXALED Shape > Appearance > USE JOINTLED: Non-admissible USE JOINTLED node inside first child of LED node.

I am wondering maybe there is any tool / method to upgrade old model automatically and save me from the painfullness in doing manually :)    Any thoughts, comments, ideas are appreciated!

Best regards,
Guangbin

Comment: I believe `WoodBox` should be renamed to `WoodenBox`. Other warnings should also be handled manually according to the message of the warning you get.

Comment: Thank you very much. The problem is solved with the suggestions.